# WIX C# custom actions with async await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wix

I have WIX installer. On one of its dialogs there is a button which calls custom action:

```
<Control X="15" Y="65" Width="100" Height="15" Type="PushButton"  Id="SetUp" Text="Set up" TabSkip="yes">
    <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="CheckingConfig" Order="3">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

CheckingConfig is C# custom action:

```
[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult CheckingConfig(Session session)
{
    try
    {
        session.StartLog("CheckingConfig");

        CheckConfiguration(session);

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
    finally
    {
        session.EndLog("CheckingConfig", ActionResult.Success);
    }
}

private static async void CheckConfiguration(Session session)
{
   CheckXmlConfig();
   CheckTxtConfig();

   await CheckDbConfig(session);

   CheckXlsConfig();
}

private static async Task<int> CheckDbConfig(Session session)
{
    // DbList = new List<ConfigEntity>();
    // read from db to list ...

    try
    {
        var tasks = DbList.Select(r => AsyncTask(r.Value)).ToList();

        session.InfoLog("...before when all");
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        session.InfoLog("...after when all");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        session.ErrorLog(e.ToString());
    }

    return 0;
}

private static Task AsyncTask(string value)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // ...
    });
}
```

And when I run installer and press the button - I receive ThreadAbortException. Does WIX support async await in Custom Actions on button click? I tried to make CheckDbConfig not async and use Task.WaitAll(tasks, 10000) and it worked. But when I use Task.WaitAll(tasks) without time, program doesn't wait for all tasks to finish execution and executes CheckXlsConfig() before all tasks completed. I do not know exact time for tasks become completed. How can I make my code working?

Answer (score -1):

So it seems that you understand the problem is that all your asynchronous tasks haven't completed before you try to return control to the installation. I'm not an async expert, but to fix this I would lean toward one of two options.

1. Fix this at the outermost level of your code, in CheckingConfig:

   ```
   session.StartLog("CheckingConfig");
   CheckConfiguration(session);
   return ActionResult.Success;
   ```

   could be replaced with something like

   ```
   session.StartLog("CheckingConfig");
   CheckConfiguration(session).Wait();
   return ActionResult.Success;
   ```
2. If you don't need the results in your installation's UI, make your custom action call asynchronous (so your installation doesn't have to wait), but consider running all the code inside it in synchronous fashion. It appears your code is only fake-async after all, given its use of Task.Run in the implementation of AsyncTask.